# Azure Container Service(AKS) Load Balancer Creation fails

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes

I'm using the Azure Container Service(AKS) to deploy an application, but I'm getting stuck on deploying a load balancer for the services. After I run `kubectl create -f deploy.yaml` and then do `kubectl describe service service-name` I get this warning from the deployment trying to create the load balancer for my app,

`Type     Reason                      Age   From                Message
  ----     ------                      ----  ----                -------
  Warning  CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  8s    service-controller  Error creating load balancer (will retry): Error getting LB for service default/stallion: azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION/resourceGroups/RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/kubernetes?api-version=2017-03-01: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '401'`

Is there something I have to do in the cloud shell so the deployment can authorize succesfully? I just followed the tutorial [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough-portal)

Comment: Can you run `kubectl get nodes` in that cloud shell?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. `kubectl get nodes` showed zero nodes and I realized that I put in the wrong value for the app secret. The deploy will still "succeed", but anything that has to create a resource will fail.